# Modeling helper functions causing cell to time out

Tags: python, pandas, function, modeling

I am trying to use the following two helper functions:

```
def fit_predict(model, 
                 X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
   # Return a dictionary of model performance indicators.
    
    results = {}
    
    # 1. Fit the model on the training set
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # 2. Predict on the training and test sets
    y_train = model.predict(X_train)
    y_test = model.predict(X_test)

    # 3. Train & test accuracy
    results['train_score'] = model.score(X_train, y_train)
    results['test_score'] = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    
    return results

def test_models(models, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    # Returns DataFrame of baseline results 
    # given a dictionary `models` of names/sklearn models.
    results = {}
    
    # Fit each model and store how it performs on the test set
    for name, model in models.items():
        
        results[name] = fit_predict(model, 
                                     X_train, y_train, 
                                     X_test, y_test)
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        results, 
        orient='index').sort_values(
            by='test_score',
            ascending=False
        )
```

to read through the dictionary of models:

```
models = {
    'linear_regression' : LinearRegression(), 
    'lasso' : LassoCV(), 
    'ridge' : RidgeCV(), 
    'elastic' : ElasticNet()
}
```

fit each, score each, and return a DataFrame.

However, whenever I run the cell, the code has ran for over two hours with no results being printed. The shape of my data is quite substantial (354,100, 38), but I am able to run just one of the items in my dictionary, linear regression, and the results get printed within minutes.

I also tried running the notebook in Google Collab and after 6m 12s the following code below was where the cell got stuck on because the time did not advance beyond 6m 12s.

```
Executing (6m 12s)  
Cell
navigate_next
test_models()
navigate_next
run_baseline()
navigate_next
fit()
navigate_next
__call__()
navigate_next
dispatch_one_batch()
navigate_next
_dispatch()
navigate_next
apply_async()
navigate_next
__init__()
navigate_next
__call__()
navigate_next
<listcomp>
navigate_next
__call__()
navigate_next
_path_residuals()
navigate_next
lasso_path()
navigate_next
enet_path()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try with only 1000 rows of your dataset to check if there are no issues in your code?

Comment: I have not but that's a good idea Pierre Loic, thank you!